# Can a legal condition be coded into an NFT-transaction?

Tags: nft, legal

I have have a question about NFT transactions. If I understand the technology correctly, tokens are transferred via the **input data** during a transaction on, for example, the Ethereum blockchain. This input data specifies which token is transferred to whom. Can other data be included in addition to this data? I am thinking of something like a legal condition ('the seller grants the buyer the copyright'). I'm aware that this legal condtion should be coded in hexadecimal code. Thank you in advance for helping me with my thesis :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically encode any extra data you want into any smart contract call, but that does not mean that it is backed up legally. In this case sure, you could have some extra data that represents copyright permission of tokens.

Its the same problem though that regular NFTs have, that being that the "Ownership" of the image represented has no legal backing behind that ownership, so you can't use ownership of an nft on chain to settle any debates in court of who owns the rights to that image.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I agree with you. In my thesis I focus on Dutch law and I suspect that a coded legal condition could be enforced. Such a transaction could be considered a copyright transfer-deed.

Comment: A note though, this functionality would be code that sits outside the erc721 or erc1155 standards for NFTs. Nfts are not defined by one standard though, so there could be a new standard invented to support such a proposed functionality.

Answer (score 1):

> Can other data be included in addition to this data? I am thinking of something like a legal condition ('the seller grants the buyer the copyright').

You can

- make terms of service available as a text/HTML file
- take this terms of service and then question from a user "I accept these terms of services"
- Hash this message + question + user address using MetaMask "Sign message" functionality
- Write user address + hash to on-chain whitelist
- Restrict NFT transfers to whitelisted users only

This way you can be sure that everyone has accepted the terms of service and you have legal grounds to go after users if they break these terms of service.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reaction! That would be a great way to enforce legal conditions! From a copyright-perspective, it would be hard, because copyright transfers require a *specific* (electronic) deed in most European Law-systems. But the proposed approach is a very interesting approach, thank you so much for your reaction!

Comment: You can make the users to sign a message on every transaction "I am transferring copyright to whoever buys this" if there is some legal argument that is has to do in particular way.